# How to get value from a bar chart on oracle apex when clicking a specific bar?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-jet

I have a bar chart on an oracle-apex page, I want to get the value from a bar when I click on it.
How can this be done?

Comment: Hi Paco, did you still need help with this? Did you see Paolo's answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new Modal Page with one Item to receive the value.
On you Barchart page go to Series -> Link -> select Redirect Page in This aplication-> and choose the target.

[image]

In the Link Builder set Page field as your Modal Page Number  and Set Items filed name = item in your modal page to receive the value

Comment: Thanks a lot Paolo!

Comment: How to enable copy/pasting from graph without reloading/redirecting to page?